# Querying Django object for number of One-to-Many related objects

Tags: django, one-to-many

I would like to update an object in Django if it has only one One-To-Many relationship (the parent object, which is being soft deleted.)

Is there a way of querying an object to find out how many Many-to-Many relationships it has?

Here's my attempt (failed):

```
  pages = Page.objects.filter(accounts=accountid)
    for page in pages:
        if page.accounts.all().count == 1:
            page.deleted = 1
            user.save()
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you have a couple of typos in your code. first one. page.accounts.all().count should be page.accounts.all().count() and also you have user.save(), you probably want page.save() instead. not sure what your model looks like, but if page.deleted is a boolean you should have page.deleted = True instead of page.deleted = 1.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about your schema but in my example a Car object has a Fk to User calles 'user':

User.objects.annotate(num_cars=Count('cars')).filter(num_cars=1)
This gives you the users that have only one car.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#joins-and-aggregates

Comment: Building off your answer, I think they can reduce their code to something like this.  Page.objects.annotate(num_accounts=Count('accounts')).filter(num_accounts=1).update(deleted=1)
 using the update function.   http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#topics-db-queries-update